# TestFlight In-App Updates: Version Number vs Build Number

Tags: ios, release, auto-update, testflight

What is the logic behind the version number and build number in TestFlight's In-App Updates? TF declares that the build number must be greater in order for the In-App Update to pop up and take place, but I always reset the build number when I increment/increase the version number.

If I change from `v1.0.0 (2)` -> `v1.0.1 (1)`, will that allow for an In-App Update to take place? Or will I have to make the update `v1.0.1 (3)`. Having the build number as `3` doesn't sit well with my OCD, as I appreciate having sensible numbers in my build histories. I would really hate to see something along the lines of `v2.0.0 (547)`.

I understand I could probably increase the build number in tandem with my version number in a nicer way (`v1.2.3 (123)`), but there are potential issues, such as `v1.2.34 (1234)` having a higher build number than `v1.3.0 (130)`.

I am releasing to clients, so I am uncomfortable testing this and I'm using a company developer account, so building random test applications probably won't look great, either. Hopefully someone may have an easy answer to my inquiry and I've overthought all of this.

I'm hoping this question is okay to ask. Based on the FAQ, I should be okay to ask about `software tools commonly used by programmers`, but I have been harassed for asking about TestFlight before.

Comment: I think you just need to get past your "OCD". I used to think about it this way but Test Flight changed my line of thinking. So Version numbers are marketing facing (1, 1.1, 1.0.1, etc.) and builds are sequential. Don't fight the tools.

Answer (score 5):

Since the old TestFlight is now replaced by iTC TestFlight, I've decided to manage my version and build numbers in a logical way. Over time, I found what works best is to break down the version numbers like so:

A version number is simply the history of your product in a numerical form. It is typically broken down as [major].[minor].[patch].[build] where the build number is optional (especially in iOS). An application is considered alpha or beta while the major number is less than 1 and is released at 1.0.0.0.

**Major**

The major number signifies a massive change in your application. Incrementing this number is appropriate when a user will need to change the way they use or think about your application.
When this number updates, deprecated functionality is expected to be dropped and the application is in a clean state. Minor and patch numbers should be reset to 0 and build should be reset to 0 or 1.

- Complete UI overhaul
- Dropped previous functionality - not deprecated
- Significant featureset added - big enough to change the use of your
  application, otherwise use sequential minor updates

**Minor**

The minor number signifies a noticeable change in your application.
When this number updates, some functionality may become deprecated, staging for being dropped in future major updates. The patch number should be reset to 0 and build set to 0 or 1.

- Added a feature
- Introduced new UI
- After a significant amount of patches that all tie into a superset

**Patch**

The patch number signifies small changes in your application.
When this number updates, the application isn't necessarily released (assuming the major is at least 1) and functionality is not deprecated.

- The build number is set to 0 or 1.
- Bug fixes
- New feature
- Non user-facing changes

**Build**

The build number signifies the developer's build index.
This number should always and only increment with each build that each developer makes. If developers are working on the same branch, the build number should increment with commits instead of builds.

Answer (score 3):

I change the version only when making feature/major bug changes.  When i'm actively working on test flights, I only change the build number each time I archive.

So it will look like v1.0 (1), then v1.0 (2) then v1.0 (3)

When I deem the app good to go to the store, the next round of development, It goes to v1.1 (4), v1.1 (5), v1.1 (6) and so on and so forth.

That's my pattern at least.  Im a single dev shop though so whatever works.

Answer (score 0):

The `build number` could be `%d.%d.%d` format. For example, `120.3.60`.

So, I put some information into `build number`.

- **Git tag count** 
  If there are 10 tags in the repository, the latest number will be 10.
- **Jenkins's build number** 
   
  I think this is more meaningful. It can help developer find out the project version in the jenkins's history.
- **A internal version**
  It is internal version number for the project. Generally, it is a decimal number for the company I works currently.

So, the build number I make maybe this format (GitTag count, Internal version, Jenkins buildNumber), Ex: `120.3.60`. (GitTag count: 120, Jenkins's buildNumber: 60, Internal version: 3).

The build number information could be generated by shell script.